# OpenCL ambiguity about CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR when using same host pointer for two devices (CPU + iGPU)

Tags: mapping, buffer, opencl, gpgpu, multi-gpu

In the web page about [clCreateBuffer](https://man.opencl.org/clCreateBuffer.html#:%7E:text=The%20result%20of%20OpenCL%20commands%20that%20operate%20on%20multiple%20buffer%20objects%20created%20with%20the%20same%20host_ptr%20or%20overlapping%20host%20regions%20is%20considered%20to%20be%20undefined.), it says

> The result of OpenCL commands that operate on multiple buffer objects
> created with the same host_ptr or overlapping host regions is
> considered to be undefined.

but it is uncertain that if "multiple buffer objects" are:

- in same context & device?
- in same context & different devices?
- different contexts & same device?
- different contexts & different devices? (my use case)
- different processes & different devices?

Also the part:

> ... overlapping host regions ...

what is the resolution here? Overlapping on same page (4kB region) with no real overlapping allowed? Or any fine-grained overlapping causes undefined behavior too?

Is the undefined behavior about drivers pinning the buffer during buffer creation? For example, if I use same host pointer for two buffers (1 on CPU and 1 on its iGPU) in OpenCL, will this cause double-pinning based undefined behavior or its just about "mapping" operations (for zero-copy access from kernel / no copy before-after needed) being unstable?

For the two buffers, I'm only doing mapping unmapping like this:

```
// user sets some data on host buffer
host_buffer[id] = data; // same host_buffer pointer used for all device_buffers

// library does copy before running a kernel
for(device: iGPU and CPU)
{
    queue[device].enqueueMapBuffer(device_buffer[device]...)
    queue[device].enqueueUnmapMemObject(device_buffer[device]...) --> now data is valid in iGPU/CPU device memory

    queue[device].enqueueNDRangeKernel(...) --> compute data
}
```

---

To overcome the undefined behavior, if single shared device buffer is the only solution, then how do different platforms behave? Can Intel discrete GPU work with same buffer that was created in AMD's CPU-device platform/context? What happens both devices run some kernels at the same time using same buffer?

OpenCL spec (https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/specs/opencl-1.0.pdf#page=56) says:

> Calling clEnqueueReadBuffer to read a region of the buffer object with
> the ptr argument value  set to host_ptr + offset, where host_ptr is a
> pointer to the memory region specified when the  buffer object being
> read is created with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, must meet the following
> requirements in order to avoid undefined behavior: • All commands that
> use this buffer object have finished execution before the read
> command begins execution. • The buffer object is not mapped. • The
> buffer object is **not used by any command-queue** until the read command
> has  finished execution

So if iGPU is not mapping (but reading instead), another command queue for the CPU can not work simultaneously not even without mapping for the same region for reading(from host to device).

Is this the right use-case:

- calculate combined mapping areas of iGPU & CPU (to evade collisions)
- map the combined area for writing to device buffer only once
- unmap the combined area only once
- run kernels on iGPU & CPU using same buffer

---

There also another issue for my use-case:

- I'm using Intel's OpenCL run-time to detect AMD CPU (Ryzen 7900)
- Intel's run-time does not detect iGPU so I use AMD's iGPU driver

So there is no shared context possible for iGPU + CPU to directly use same buffer. There has to be some kind of migration but without extra copying (to not kill the advantage of using CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR) but there is no comment about this. How does Intel's driver on AMD CPU behave when RAM-sharing with iGPU inside AMD's driver?

How to migrate a buffer while making sure it does not copy anything?

Comment: In short, I think if you're using a read-only buffer, you can run two or more devices on it only if not more than one of the buffer objects is created with ..HOST_PTR set, the others using copies. For read-write buffers, you're just out of luck. There's no well-defined way to process it in parallel on multiple OpenCL devices. I think you can partition a host buffer and process them in parallel as the sub-buffers would not overlap. That's my take on it, but I could be wrong.

Comment: If I constrain igpu or cpu to normal copying, their advantage is partially lost (at least they still have bandwidth of RAM) but seems like there is no other option. Better than nothing at least.